# can we add form on activeadmin index page in rails 4

Tags: forms, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I'm rendering a partial in my index page

```
index do
.
.
  div id: "overlay-select-period" do
    render partial: "select_period", locals: { period:  GoalCalender.legend_name_year, record: UsersGoalCalender.new }
  end
.
.
end
```

and in this partial (.html.erb) under app/views/admin/users_goal_calendars, I'm having rails form helper form_for used
but when I run the app, it doesn't show the form tag on the view `<form></form>`

can anyone tell me whether we can add such form in activeadmin index page?

> P.S. I've tried all other ways to add form (formtastic, simple form
>   and form_tag), and writing the form directly inside `index do...end`
>   (without rendering a partial) with no luck

Comment: Is this your partial file? app/views/admin/users_goal_calendars/_select_period.html.erb
 Furthermore, does your partial file contain <form> </form> inside it?

Comment: Yes @Jay-Ar Polidario, in my partial I've used form-for

Comment: Hmm... I haven't tried customising ActiveAdmin view files yet, so I don't think I could help. But I just hope I could still help. 1) Does your partial file contain something like this? <%= form_for record do %>...<% end %> 2) Have you tried including a random string inside that partial file just to check if it actually gets called? i.e. <div>jdfljsdfljasdlasjdldjlasdkj</div> and check if this random string appears in the page?

Comment: You can add forms in activeadmin - this might be helpful, http://activeadmin.info/docs/5-forms.html

Comment: I've observed one more thing here that when I'm using form_for it shows the input field which I've added (i.e. <input type="submit"> and all )but not it's enclosing form tag `<form> ... </form>`

Comment: Not sure if it helps you any, but this is typically indicative of a form being nested inside of another form.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but I just discovered myself that AA somehow removes your form tag if batch actions are enabled.

This is because enabling batch actions wraps most of the page in a form and nested forms are not fun.

The mention something about it here if you scroll all the down: https://activeadmin.info/9-batch-actions.html

I tried disabling batch actions and the form tag comes back.